# Multiple selected File names to specific <td> elements

Tags: html, file, upload, html-table

I want to select multiple files for upload and show the names of the files in a table.
I found something similar in this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/bdbXk/

This fiddle uses li elements. but i want the list to get inserted into specific td elements identified by id or class.

What I am trying is depicted in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/5vecv/5/

the file names should only be inserted into the td having class as "files". or only the first td of every row..

Comment: make a table, update the jsfiddle, then tell us where in that table you want the value to go.